# At what outdoor temperature does compost break down?

Tags: composting

Looking at [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-can-i-use-my-balcony-compost-during-winter), I see that composting doesn't really happen in the winter without external insulation or heat. At what outdoor temperature (or temperature range) does composting occur? Does it make sense to start a compost pile in the winter with below 0C average temperatures?

Comment: I think that the biggest advantage of posting on gardening SE is that you're much more likely to get several good answers. And there's nothing in the question that ties it in uniquely to sustainability.

Answer (score 4):

When composting you should look at the inside temperature of the pile, because that's where all the action is so to speak. The bigger the pile the more insulated the inside is and the better the contents of the pile will continue to decompose when it gets colder outside. If I remember correctly, the inside of a compost pile should be between 30 and 60°C (86-140°F). Below 30°C the process slows down a lot and above 70°C (158°F) too many organisms will die.

To give a very rough estimate; outside temperature needs to be above 7°C (45°F) for a medium-sized compost heap without insulation to work, so starting at 0°C (32°F) probably doesn't work (until the temperature rises).

Comment: But the material also wouldn't decompose, right? So starting to save organic material (rather than throwing it away) might make sense, just without any expectation that it will do much until things warm up.

Comment: Can you define medium-sized?

Comment: @HighlyIrregular 350-400 liters